# Makefile does not evaluate OBJECTS variable

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, shared-libraries

I am trying to build a Makefile that will build a shared library with g++ and I find that it is not evaluating the OBJECTS variable. This is on Ubuntu 18.04 and all the files are in the same current directory. Secondly it is completely skipping the source file compilation and proceeding directly to evaluate the linking instruction. As a clarification I am using GNU Make 4.1

Here is what I get when I type make all

```
g++  -shared -pthread   -o   tree.so
g++: fatal error: no input files
 compilation terminated.
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'tree.so' failed
make: *** [tree.so] Error 1
```

Here is my Makefile code

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include -Wall -std=c++17 -O3   -march=native -Ofast -ftree-vectorize
LIBS=-shared -pthread 
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(wildcard *.o)
TARGET=tree.so


all:$(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC)  $(LIBS)  -o $(OBJECTS)  $(TARGET)

$(OBJECTS):$(SOURCES)
        $(CC)  -c -g $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES)

clean:
       rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Unrelated: You might like using sort, such as:   "SOURCES=$(sort $(wildcard *.cpp))".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have the `*.cpp` files in your directories, then there is not any `*.o` yet, so your `$(wildcard *.o)` will expand to nothing.

What you want is to get the `*.cpp` files and compute the corresponding `*.o` files:

```
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

or equivalently:

```
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```

Now, your compiler command is not the best one, because if you touch any source file all will be compiled. You can use instead:

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp
         $(CC) -c -g $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

So that only the touched files are actually rebuilt.

Also you have the linking command wrong. It should be:

```
$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC)  $(LIBS)  -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
```

because the argument to the `-o` option is the *output* file, that is the target.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made the modifications. I still get the same error. The OBJECTS variable is not evaluated.

Comment: @gansub. Sorry, the `$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)` was written backwards (fixed). Also your linking command was wrong, I've fixed that too. I actually tested it and it works now.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out ! But it still gives me the same message :(. I am not sure why. I made three changes. One is to the definition of OBJECTS. Then source file compilation target and finally to the linking. Each time I just copied from your answer and I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you running `make` from the directory containing the `.cpp` files?  What output do you see from `$(info SOURCES=[$(SOURCES)])`?

Comment: @G.M. Sorry I seem to have deleted them accidentally. Now it works and answer accepted !